# Old scifi movie with female aliens and female protagonist

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, animation

There was this old animated scifi movie I watched as kid. All I remember is there’s a female who is the main character with white hair I think and she eventually gets abducted by these female alien creatures to their planet and I remember they trapped her to the ground and they were all circling around her like a cult. I also remember a scene of her on a train. The movie was probably made in the 80s/90s.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that you can remember more than you've put down. For example, when were you a kid? Was this movie recent or older? Was it in black-and-white or colour? Was the woman young, adult or elderly? What was her name? Was the train futuristic or contemporary? How do you know that the aliens were aliens? Was the film for adults (with sex and gore) or more child-friendly?

Comment: In *Monsters vs. Aliens* (2009), the protagonist is a white-haired woman who at one point gets abducted by aliens. However, I don't remember the aliens as female, and the protagonist was 50' tall, which you would probably have remembered.

Comment: Was this anime? CGI? Or some other style of animation?